# How to get position of empty SVG group?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm working with d3, and I have trouble with positioning and empty groups.

I have this svg:

```xml
<svg id="mysvg" height="200" width="1350" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="translate(50, 6)">
    <g class="a">
      <g transform="translate(0,161.3919677734375)" style="opacity: 1;">
        <line y2="0" x2="-6"></line>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g class="b">
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I want to dynamically add a **line** to group with class `b`, and I want to add it so the coordinates of the **first point** of the line will coincide with the coordinates of the **second point** of the line inside group `a`.

Since coordinates of SVG objects are relative to their containers, to get the relative coordinates I get first the absolute position of the line inside `g.a` and the absolute position of `g.b`, using `getBoundingClientRect()`

The problem is coordinates of `g.b`, if it's empty, are **completely messed up**. I have to create a **bogus object** to get them properly:

```js
d3.select("#mysvg .b").append("circle").attr("r", 0).attr("fill", "transparent")
                                       .attr("cx", 0).attr("cy", 0);
```

Furthermore, if I create the circle with a radius **greater than zero**, the position of its group `b` **will shift**.

Comment: Empty `<g>` objects don't really have a position as they auto size to their contents. The position of the `<g>` should shift if you put stuff in it, that's how `<g>` elements work.

Comment: getBBox() helped me get positions of svg elements before. maybe you didn't  know about it so that is why I'm mentioning it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use basic DOM interfaces to transform between both coordinate systems. Interface [`InterfaceSVGLocatable`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable) defines method [`getTransformToElement()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getTransformToElement) which

> Returns the transformation matrix from the user coordinate system on the current element (after application of the ‘transform’ attribute, if any) to the user coordinate system on parameter element (after application of its ‘transform’ attribute, if any).

It is worth noting, that support for this was dropped from Chrome 48+ ([Issue 524432](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=524432)). However, there is a rather slim polyfill available:

```
// Polyfill needed for Chrome 48+
SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement = 
    SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement || function(elem) {
        return elem.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(this.getScreenCTM());
    };
```

Because it is just this one simple line, it might even be easier to directly use it within your code.

You may than use a helper [`SVGPoint`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InterfaceSVGPoint) to get the transformation matrix needed to [transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#__svg__SVGPoint__matrixTransform) from elements in your group `a` to elements in group `b`:

```
// Create a helper point
var point = document.getElementById("mysvg").createSVGPoint();
point.x = line.getAttribute("x2");
point.y = line.getAttribute("y2");

// Calculate starting point of new line based on transformation between coordinate systems.
point = point.matrixTransform(line.getTransformToElement(groupB));
```

Have a look at this working example, which draws a red line in group `b` starting at the end of the line in group `a` to coordinates (100, 100):

```js
// Polyfill needed for Chrome >48
SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement = SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement || function(elem) {
    return elem.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(this.getScreenCTM());
};

var groupB = document.querySelector("g.b");
var line = document.querySelector(".a line");

// Create a helper point
var point = document.getElementById("mysvg").createSVGPoint();
point.x = line.getAttribute("x2");
point.y = line.getAttribute("y2");

// Calculate starting point of new line based on transformation between coordinate systems.
point = point.matrixTransform(line.getTransformToElement(groupB));

// D3 applied to simplify matters a little.
// New line is drawn from end of line in group a to (100,100).
d3.select(groupB).append("line")
    .attr({
        "x1": point.x,
        "y1": point.y,
        "x2": 100,
        "y2": 100
    });
```

```css
line {
  stroke: black;
}

.b line{
  stroke:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="mysvg" height="200" width="1350" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="translate(50, 6)">
    <g class="a">
      <g transform="translate(0,161.3919677734375)" style="opacity: 1;">
        <line y2="0" x2="-40"></line>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g class="b">
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

---

Because questions were raised in the comments regarding the performance of this approach compared to the one proposed by the question itself, I have set up a little [jsPerf test case](http://jsperf.com/get-empty-svg-g-coordinates) to compare both. I would suspect this answer's code to significantly outperform the original one because manipulating the DOM is always an expensive operation. The matrix calculations on the other hand will only have to use values from the DOM without applying any modifications. The results clearly back this assumption with the insertion of a circle being at least 95% slower in FF, IE and Chrome.

[image]

Comment: It seems Firefox has no `getScreenCTM()`. I'm using Firefox 41.0.2.

Comment: I think it **should** be there. It seems to have been quite buggy in lower versions, but I don't think it is gone.

Comment: @MarcoSulla FF does actually have the method `getTransformToElement ()` and shouldn't even run the code of the polyfill. Did you use the polyfill as it is or the did you extract the one-liner? When doing the latter, remember to  replace `this` with the element to transform to, because in that case `this` will most likely refer to another object, which might indeed not implement the method.

Comment: @MarcoSulla Firefox certainly does have getScreenCTM

Comment: Yes sorry, `getScreenCTM` is supported and the code works, but for what I see, I always need an helper point. Is this solution more fast?

Comment: @MarcoSulla What do you mean by *more fast*, faster than *what*? According to the spec *"An SVGPoint is an (x, y) coordinate pair."* which is never actually drawn but rather used as input for the matrix calculations.

Comment: Well, faster than the solution I described in my question, with `getBoundingClientRect()`.

Comment: @MarcoSulla Out of curiosity I set up a performance test case to compare both approaches. Have a look at the updated answer for the results.